# mixpanel Function.prototype.bind is taking reference of already define function in project

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypejs, mixpanel

I am working in project which is already using prototype.js , where in some files are included on fly containing mixpanel.min.js .

After some I am getting Error in console.

I found that protype.js contains below method ,

```
 Function.prototype.bind = function() {
  var __method = this, args = $A(arguments), object = args.shift();
  return function() {
    return __method.apply(object, args.concat($A(arguments)));
  }
}
```

and maxpanel is taking its reference and goes into infinite call at this line ,

```
 N = Function.prototype.bind
```

Getting Console Error

> prototype.js:452 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Which version of PrototypeJS ? Function#bind was changed to a polyfill in 1.7.1 released in 2012. If you are able to upgrade to this version or later that should fix the problem.

Comment: version is pretty old version 1.5.1_rc3 also i can't change version as Products has many function depending on that, change will cause regression 
 test for product and then fixing . is there any other way to used this both on page without breaking any functionality?

Comment: you *could* manually edit the Function#bind definition in the prototype.js file to be the new polyfill - but I'm not sure if that would work as expected